# Cannot install apache-airflow-providers-mysql==1.0.0 and apache-airflow-providers-mysql==1.0.1 package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: django, airflow

I am trying to install apache-airflow-providers-mysql

I have use the following command

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

But I a, getting an error like this

[image]

Comment: try `pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql --upgrade`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error is shown in a screenshot which is not accessible to screen readers.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

For Debian 8 or older

```sh
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

For Debian > 8

```sh
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

And then try installing apache-airflow-providers-mysql